# Local time is ahead of PHP date() command?

Tags: php, timezone

I am trying to get the local time on a server (Timezone is "Asia/Kolkata").

The code I have outputs a time that us about 1 hour behind the actual time. Here is the snippet:

```
<?php

// your code goes 
echo date_default_timezone_get();
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
//echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo $timestamp;

echo "Hello\n";

$dt = new DateTime("now");
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
echo $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

Output is: UTCAsia/Kolkata2015-01-21 15:46:16Hello
2015-01-21 15:46:16

whereas the actual time is: 2015-01-21 16:38

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If it's actually 52 minutes off like you showed, then your system clock is probably just not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try to change php.ini file.

find date.timezone then change value to Asia/Kolkata.

then let me know if it works.

Comment: that's one way of doing it. but why does the above code not work?